# Changing annontation image on iOS depending on object type

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to change image of a `MKMarkerAnnontationView` depending on which value the annotation contains. All annotations get the same image using this code, and i need somehow the image to be set depending on which value the user chooses. So when the user presses another type of parking, the same object is being used, but with another type.

I tried to force the annotations to reload, but I didn't get that to work. Any pointers to help me?

```
if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {

            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.glyphTintColor = UIColor.white
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

            if annotation.type == .bus {
                view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bus")
            } else if annotation.type == .disabled {
                view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "disabled")
            } else if annotation.type == .MC {
                view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "mc")
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: can you add debugPrint(annotation.type) before your if else block and make sure that types are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem like that and the only way I solved it was to remove all data points from the MKMapView and then readd them with the only difference that in the func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) i was checking whitch title the MKAnnotationView had.
To achieve that I created an object class that extended MKAnnotationView witch also had a title variable so the list of my annotations was that classes objects. 
When the user changes the image of the MKAnnotation you change the title variable in the choice and you first do

```
self.sceneView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
```

and after you re-add the annotation points. The delegate function that will get called will be like that

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views{
        if((view.annotation is MKUserLocation) == false){
            // Resize image
            let dt:DataPoint = view.annotation as! DataPoint //Data point is my class
            var pinImage:UIImage!
            if(dt.title = "example"){
                pinImage = exampleImage
                size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60) //whetever size
            }else{
                pinImage = anotherImage
            }
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            pinImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            view.image = resizedImage
        }
    }
}
```